# overriding ko.computed not working

Tags: knockout.js

Concider if we want to override a function for a specific object (not in a subclass):

```
var Animal = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.hello = ko.computed(function() {
    return 'Not implemented hello';
  });

  self.greeting = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.hello() + '!!';
  });
};

var dog = new Animal();
dog.hello = ko.computed(function() {
  return 'Wooff';
});
console.log(dog.greeting());
```

I expected the output to be: `Wooff!!`

But it was: `Not implemented hello!!`

Here is a jsbin where I've implemented it in plain JavaScript which works and in knockout which doesn't: http://jsbin.com/uyilot/1/edit

** **edit** **

The jsbin with Ryan's solution (now working!) : http://jsbin.com/uyilot/2/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that a `ko.computed` is evaluated immediately when it is created, by default. It is only re-evaluated when one of its dependencies changes.  In your scenario, there are no dependencies that are being updated that would cause `greeting` to be re-evaluated.

One choice is to use the `deferEvaluation` flag to prevent the computed from being evaluated until it is first accessed.  It would look like:

```
self.greeting = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return self.hello() + '!!';
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
});
```

Otherwise, if `greeting` depends on some specific observable and that observable is updated, then it would get re-evaluated as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird scenario, since the dependencies of `ko.computed` are recorded only when the `computed` is evaluated *at the first time*. When `greeting` is evaluated for the first time, Knockout references the `self.hello`. When you change the reference of `self.hello` to a different computed variable, the dependencies are not updated.

To fix the problem, we can make `self.hello` itself an `observable`:

```
self.hello = ko.observable(ko.computed(function() {
    return 'Not implemented hello';
}));
```

and in `self.greeting`, reference `self.hello` like this:

```
self.greeting = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.hello()() + '!!';
});
```

When you need to update `self.hello`, you can do:

```
dog.hello(ko.computed(function() {
  return 'Wooff';
}));
```

I also put together a modified example in JSBin for your reference: http://jsbin.com/ogajaw/1/edit.

After all, this is a weird example. But it works.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the weird scenario, I think I simplified it one step too far.